# can I jail ssh for more that one directory?

Tags: ssh, jail

I have working jail ssh to one directory.

I would love to give **r/w access** for the **jail ssh user** to **few directories**. For example

- /tmp/user
- /home/user
- /srv/www/user

is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot symlink to anything that is not inside the chroot'ed environment.

I would suggest doing a `mount --bind`:

(assuming the user's chroot directory is `/home/john`

```
mount --bind /tmp/john /home/john/tmp/john
mount --bind /srv/www/john /home/john/srv/www/john
```

Comment: sounds good. Let me try that

Answer (score 0):

You can create the directories under /home/user, and then symlink them to the original places.
The only problem I see is that the users /tmp will not have the /tmp's noexec.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot symlink to something that is outside a chroot'ed environment...

Comment: Of course not, I proposed the other way around, create the directory under his chroot and symlink to for example /srv/www/user